# Как сменить разрешение экрана qt eglfs?

Tags: qt, qt5, embedded

Дано: ушатанные мониторы, мерцают при 1280*1024. Доступа к рут  давать не хочется.

Как поменять разрешение экрана из qt?

Или как сохранить конфигурацию дисплея в json файл, чтоб после перезагрузки настроиться по нему?

Не известно на каком конекторе подключен монитор.

Comment: Изменить средствами qt нельзя, только системными функциями. А вот получить можно - QApplication::primaryScreen вернет QScreen основного монитора, сохранить в json тоже не проблема

Comment: игрушки ж меняют равзрешение монитора ) будем смотреть

Comment: Игрушки меняют сознание, что уж говорить о мониторах )) Лдано, например, в винде, разрешение меняется через winapi вот так https://www.eastfist.com/qt_tutorials/index.php/2014/10/26/how-to-change-screen-resolution-in-windows-using-qt/ у вас, думаю, будет нечто похожее

Comment: да в основном kms, но хотелось бы и на xcb и на винде)